# how to highlight multi-line code blocks in geany

Tags: highlight, geany

In komodo you have code blocks highlighted with a vertical dotted line as shown in the following image [image: here].

Is there anything like that in geany?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As no one answered me here, I wrote to the geany mailing list and they show me how to obtain this in geany too:
it's called "indentation guides", and the setting is in

> edit-> preferences-> editor-> display-> show > indentation guides

Thank you to **Colomban Wendling** of the geany mailing list!
I leave this answer here for future reference to help someone else who needs the same.

Comment: Though this is not exactly what i was looking for, but it is still helpful. And Geany editor should have provided highlighting only that closing tag whose opening tag is selected. Thanks.